# Co-occurence analysis in Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher, counting

Let's say I have a database with nodes of two types Candyjars and Candies. Every Candyjar (Candyjar1, Candyjar2...) has different number of candies of different types: CandyRed, CandyGreen etc..

Now let's say the end game here is to find how much is the probability of the various types of candies to occur together, and the covariance among them. Then I want to have  relationships between each CandyType with an associated probabilities of co-occurence and covariance.  Let's call this relationships OCCURS_WITH so that Candtype1 -[OCCURS_WITH]->Candytype2 and Candytype1 -[COVARIES]->Candytype2

I'd make a database with CandieTypes and CandyJars as nodes, make a relationship  (cj:CandyJar)-[r:CONTAINS]->(ct:Candytype) where r can have an attribute to set "how many" candy of a type are cotained in the jar.

Noy my problems is that I don't understand how can i, in Cypher, make a query to assign the OCCURS_WITH relationship in an optimal manner. Would I have to iterate for every pair of Candies, counting the number of pairs that cooccurs in candyjars over the number of candyjars? Is there a way to do it for all of the possible pairs together?
When I try to do:

```
MATCH  (ct1:Candytype)<-[r1:CONTAINS]-(cj:Candyjar)-[r2:CONTAINS]->(ct2:Candytype)
    WHERE ct1<>ct2 AND ct1.name="CandyRed" AND ct2.name="CandyBlue"
    RETURN  ct1,r1,count(r1),cj1,ct2,r2,count(r2)
    LIMIT 5
```

I cannot get the count of the relationships of the co-occurring candies that I would need to express the probability of co-occurrence.

Would I have to use something like python to do the calculations rather than try to make a statement in Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of how many times CandyRed and CandyBlue co-occur, you can use the following Cypher statement:

```
MATCH  (ct1:Candytype)<-[:CONTAINS]-(:Candyjar)-[:CONTAINS]->(ct2:Candytype)
WHERE ct1.name="CandyRed" AND ct2.name="CandyBlue"
RETURN  ct1,ct2, count(*) AS coOccur
LIMIT 5
```

If you want a query that will compare all the candy types, you can use:

```
MATCH  (ct1:Candytype)<-[:CONTAINS]-(:Candyjar)-[:CONTAINS]->(ct2:Candytype)
WHERE id(ct1) < id(ct2)
RETURN  ct1,ct2, count(*) AS coOccur
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm working with Neo4j desktop, and in this way I would be counting the nodes but I wouldn't be able to display the graph which wouldn't be ideal as i cannot see whats happening. 
What I mean is, if you imagine the graph that you stated you would imagine ct1 connecting to some CandyJars connectintg to ct2 . But if I try to display the graph like stated (which implies returning ct1,ct2, candjyjars and relationships), the count statement will not behave as I intend. Is there a way to display the full  graph AND count the relationships at the same time?

Comment: You need to store the count into new reoationship

Comment: What do you mean, first I have to get the count with a query  and store it( query1), then I can use it in a subsequent query? 

To clarify my problem I would want in the output a table that is structured like A or B:
A) ct1.name,r1.amount,cj.id, r2.amount,ct2.name, COUNTS(r1)
B) ct1.name, cj.id , ct2.name, LIST(r1), LIST(r2), COUNTS(r1)
Where counts(r1) has to be the amount of total relationships that match the pattern and LIST(r1) is a list of all the relationship objects. If it is possible with a single query. Is it possible?